# Wrong return type in `map` Kotlin

Tags: android, dictionary, kotlin

I don't know what's wrong with my dead simple piece of Kotlin code:

```kotlin
fun scan(): List<File> {
    val comics: List<File> = ArrayList()

    val extPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath.toString()
    File(extPath).walkTopDown()
        .forEach { file ->
            if (isComic(file)) {
                comics.add(file)
            }
        }

    return comics
}


fun getComics(): List<Comic> {
    return scan().map { comicFile ->
        val comic = Comic()
        comic.path = comicFile.path.toString()
        return comic
    }
}
```

(I understand that `getExternalStorageDirectory()` is depreciated now, just a quick  dirty way for a Kotlin crash course)

Android Studio complains that I should return `List<Comic>` in the transform function.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    fun getComics(): List<Comic> {
    return scan().map { comicFile ->
        val comic = Comic()
        comic.path = comicFile.path.toString()
        comic
    }
}
```

remove the 'return', {} is a inline funtion, it will return the 'comic: Comic' as the result of getComics() if u use 'return comic' in a inline funtion

Answer (score 3):

Return statement in inline lambdas are used to return from the scope of parent function, Qualified returns or the last line can be used in this case:

```kotlin
fun getComics(): List<Comic> {
    return scan().map { comicFile ->
        val comic = Comic()
        comic.path = comicFile.path.toString()
        return@map comic  // qualified returns
    }
}
```

And you can also change the name of the lambda if they are ambiguous and nested with `map name@ { return@name ... }`.

But actually you can do this one-liner:

```kotlin
fun getComics(): List<Comic> {
    return scan().map { comicFile ->
        Comic().apply { path = comicFile.path.toString() }  // last line return
    }
}
```